# Pass dynamic id value in jquery Load function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pass dynamic id in Jquery Load function and getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" error. How can I concatenate my id with Jquery selector? 
I want when my value gets updated through the ajax then reload the div based on Dynamic id.
Please see my code below:

```
<script>
function update_function(target,name,pid,empid) {
  var data = target.textContent;
  var id=pid;

  $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax.php',
      method: 'GET',
      data: { emp_id: empid, col_status:data },
      success: function (data){
          $("#"+id+").load(location.href + #"+id+");
           console.log(id);

      }
  });


}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: $("#"+id).load(location.href + "#"+id);

Comment: Typo. Your quotes are all messed up. `$("#" + id).load(location.href + " #" + id);`. Note that the space before the `#` is important as it means you're looking for an element with that `id` in the HTML response, not sending a URL fragment. I'd suggest using an IDE with syntax highlighting as it makes issues like thie very obvious - as you can see in the code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the template literals to decrease the confusion.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```js
<script>
function update_function(target,name,pid,empid) {
  var data = target.textContent;
  var id=pid;

  $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax.php',
      method: 'GET',
      data: { emp_id: empid, col_status:data },
      success: function (data){
          $(`#${id}`).load(`${location.href}#${id}`);
           console.log(id);
      }
  });


}
</script>
```

Comment: hey https://stackoverflow.com/users/7867822/anurag-srivastava you missed the `$` sign :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the changes I made to your concatenation, as well as some of the bracing structure.  Other than that, you were close.  This should compile.

```
<script>
    function update_function(target,name,pid,empid) {
      var data = target.textContent;
      var id=pid;

      $.ajax({
          url: 'ajax.php',
          method: 'GET',
          data: { emp_id: empid, col_status:data },
          success: function (data) {
          $("#" + id).load(location.href + "#" + id)
             console.log(id);
          }     
       });
    }
</script>
```